# How can I have two scripts that call for two different ajax libraries run at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, accordion

I honestly have very little knowledge on jquerys and javascripts; however, I seem to have a problem of trying to call two ajax jquery libraries at once.

On my webpage, I have an accordion that clicks to toggle open. I also have a side menu directory that also clicks to toggle open. Both of them have their own script to call their own ajax library.

I have noticed that leaving the script that allows the accordion to toggle open would break the side menu toggle... as in clicking the side menu toggle button would redirect to an error page. Vice versa, if I remove the accordion script and leave only the side menu script, the side menu would work, but the accordion would no longer be clickable and cannot open.

Is there any way to make both script run at the same time? I really appreciate the help!

The parts in my code:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/common.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- The script for the side menu -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-110784497-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-110784497-1');
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- The script for the accordion -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<header>
<div id="drawer">
    <button id="toggle_button">
        <a class="toggle" href="javascript void(0)">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
    </button>

    <nav id="s_nav">
        <p class="s_logo"><a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/bg/01.png" width="200" alt="store"></a></p>
        <div class="scroll">
            <ul class="txt18 futura">
                <li><a href="../index.html#helloWrp">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="../covid/">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="../service/">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="../head_spa/">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="../products/">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="../policy/">Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="../inquiry/">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="../recruit/">Link 8</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="address">
              <p class="txt16 futura">Call Now</p>
                <a class="txt10 tel wht" href="tel:123456789">123456789</a>
                <a href="mailto:email.com" class="txt10 mail wht">email.com</a>
                <p class="txt10">Address</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>

<main>
<section id="recruitWrp" class="inner1000">

    <h1 class="tit_content futura"><font color="999999">- HEADER -</font></h1>

    <div id="photoWrp"></div>

    <br><br>

    <p class="txt16">
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. Bacon venison swine porchetta meatloaf pork chop salami. Landjaeger biltong turducken bresaola, shank porchetta pork chop pig pancetta alcatra filet mignon brisket venison. Tenderloin prosciutto flank, pork loin biltong meatball filet mignon cupim ham boudin. Kielbasa turkey jerky, ham doner leberkas salami meatball capicola sausage ground round alcatra
    </p>


<div class="bootstrap inner1000">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="font-family: Futura; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><b>✚　Title 1</b></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <br>
          <p align="center" style="font-weight: bold;">Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. </p>
          <br>
          <img style="float: left; "src="../img/bg/01.png" width="300"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. Bacon venison swine porchetta meatloaf pork chop salami. Landjaeger biltong turducken bresaola, shank porchetta pork chop pig pancetta alcatra filet mignon brisket venison. Tenderloin prosciutto flank, pork loin biltong meatball filet mignon cupim ham boudin. Kielbasa turkey jerky, ham doner leberkas salami meatball capicola sausage ground round alcatra.</p>
          <p>　Strip steak sirloin kevin t-bone pork, andouille hamburger frankfurter chuck leberkas shankle. Tail bacon tongue cupim meatball tri-tip bresaola boudin meatloaf kielbasa chuck chicken ball tip tenderloin. Short ribs shoulder jowl, jerky corned beef drumstick leberkas venison meatball chicken. Tenderloin turkey andouille leberkas hamburger. Doner chicken beef ribs cupim, tongue pastrami ham hock chuck ham salami cow. Ham ham hock pork salami doner kevin pork chop landjaeger beef ribs boudin hamburger chuck pig tail. </p>>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="font-family: Futura; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><b>✚　Title 2</b></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <br>
          <p align="center" style="font-weight: bold;">Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. </p>
          <br>
          <img style="float: left; "src="../img/bg/01.png" width="300"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. Bacon venison swine porchetta meatloaf pork chop salami. Landjaeger biltong turducken bresaola, shank porchetta pork chop pig pancetta alcatra filet mignon brisket venison. Tenderloin prosciutto flank, pork loin biltong meatball filet mignon cupim ham boudin. Kielbasa turkey jerky, ham doner leberkas salami meatball capicola sausage ground round alcatra.</p>
          <p>　Strip steak sirloin kevin t-bone pork, andouille hamburger frankfurter chuck leberkas shankle. Tail bacon tongue cupim meatball tri-tip bresaola boudin meatloaf kielbasa chuck chicken ball tip tenderloin. Short ribs shoulder jowl, jerky corned beef drumstick leberkas venison meatball chicken. Tenderloin turkey andouille leberkas hamburger. Doner chicken beef ribs cupim, tongue pastrami ham hock chuck ham salami cow. Ham ham hock pork salami doner kevin pork chop landjaeger beef ribs boudin hamburger chuck pig tail. </p>>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="font-family: Futura; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><b>✚　Title 3</b></a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <br>
          <p align="center" style="font-weight: bold;">Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. </p>
          <br>
          <img style="float: left; "src="../img/bg/01.png" width="300"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet porchetta kevin tri-tip, beef pork chop pastrami flank meatball. Bacon venison swine porchetta meatloaf pork chop salami. Landjaeger biltong turducken bresaola, shank porchetta pork chop pig pancetta alcatra filet mignon brisket venison. Tenderloin prosciutto flank, pork loin biltong meatball filet mignon cupim ham boudin. Kielbasa turkey jerky, ham doner leberkas salami meatball capicola sausage ground round alcatra.</p>
          <p>　Strip steak sirloin kevin t-bone pork, andouille hamburger frankfurter chuck leberkas shankle. Tail bacon tongue cupim meatball tri-tip bresaola boudin meatloaf kielbasa chuck chicken ball tip tenderloin. Short ribs shoulder jowl, jerky corned beef drumstick leberkas venison meatball chicken. Tenderloin turkey andouille leberkas hamburger. Doner chicken beef ribs cupim, tongue pastrami ham hock chuck ham salami cow. Ham ham hock pork salami doner kevin pork chop landjaeger beef ribs boudin hamburger chuck pig tail. </p>>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <p class="txt16">
    Strip steak sirloin kevin t-bone pork, andouille hamburger frankfurter chuck leberkas shankle. Tail bacon tongue cupim meatball tri-tip bresaola boudin meatloaf kielbasa chuck chicken ball tip tenderloin. Short ribs shoulder jowl, jerky corned beef drumstick leberkas venison meatball chicken. Tenderloin turkey andouille leberkas hamburger. Doner chicken beef ribs cupim, tongue pastrami ham hock chuck ham salami cow. Ham ham hock pork salami doner kevin pork chop landjaeger beef ribs boudin hamburger chuck pig tail.
    </p>

</main>
```

[This is how the site looks normally with niether of the side menu or the accordion toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73AnF.png)

[This is how the side menu looks when you click the toggle button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20aYk.png)

[This is how the accordion looks when you click the panel to toggle it open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdZXn.png)

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. We are missing the CSS and the script for the side menu. the better solution is to have the side menu in bootstrap too

Comment: Also DO NOT load more than one jQuery

Comment: Normally you shouldn't load multiple versions of jQuery. If you really need to do this, you have to make use of `jQuery.noConflict()` in one of your scripts.

Comment: Nah, they just need to use the same code

Comment: Wait, where in your code is the actual script that *uses* these jQuery libraries?

Comment: You would have to make use of [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) in HTML, which you can add to an HTML element using jQuery with something like `$("#s_nav").addClass('open');`. Then in your CSS you can select that class and have the element stay open

Comment: Truthfully speaking, I didn't create the code for the side menu. A designer created the overall layout for my website including the side menu and I am not sure where the CSS or script for the side menu is. Nevertheless, I would rather not touch that part of the code since I am only working on a single page right now while the side menu exist on every page. Unfortunately, I have lost contact with that designer so I can't ask him for help. As for the accordion, I didn't add any CSS code for that part.

Comment: I just tried to copy my whole html code and the css code into the snippet editor and the side menu wasn't working as it does on my site. So I'm assuming that part of the code is done through a jquery?